# Angular 2 animations: Move image smoothly

Tags: angular, animation, css-animations

I put an image in my angular 2 component html, and I would like to move it to another position in the screen when clicking it.

```
<img (tap)="toggleThrow()" [@throw]="throw"
               src="test.png">
```

I added the following animation trigger:

```
trigger('throw', [
    state('yes', style({
        left: '100px',
        top: '200px'
      })),
      transition('void => yes', animate('600ms ease-in')),
      transition('yes => void', animate('600ms ease-in')),
  ]),
```

and the following method after clicking:

```
toggleThrow() {
    if (!this.throw)
      this.throw = 'yes';
    else
      this.throw = null;
  }
```

Whenever I click the image, the image changes position. The problem is that it actually disspaer in one place, and appear in the second place, instead moving elegantly pixel by pixel from one place to another.

How I can move an image smoothly between X and Y positions to get a throw-like animation?

Currently it just appears in the new place immadiately.

Comment: Provide plunker :)

Comment: @Kinduser I really have no idea how to work witha plunker and import what I need, the question is really descriptibe with all my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is combining the *null* and *void* states and keyword.

You could do something like

```
  state('yes', style({
    left: '100px',
    top: '200px'
  })),
  transition('* => yes', animate('600ms ease-in')),
  transition('yes => *', animate('600ms ease-in')),
])
```

And

```
  if (!this.throw) this.throw = 'yes';
  else this.throw = "";
```